# Can't connect to pgpool

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgpool

I'm playing around [pgpool2](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page).

I'm connecting to postgresql which is running on port 5432 with command `psql -U postgres -p 5432` and it's connecting normally.

When I'm connecting to pgpool2 running on 9999 port with command `psql -U postgres -p 9999` - it returns back dialog like: 
`psql: root@master:/linux/path#`

What I'm doing wrong? Is there way to connect to pgpool using psql? 
I cannot connect to it from application also.

**UPD** I've got following error `pool_do_auth: maybe protocol version mismatch (current version 3)`

**Solved** : Problem was in pgpool auth on backends. Editing `pg_hba.conf` fixed problem.

Comment: Can you share what you changed? I'm having a similar issue and can only get it to work by using 'trust' in `pg_hba.conf`

Comment: @skroth, what version of pgpool you use?

Comment: `pgpool-II version 3.1.3 (hatsuiboshi)`

Comment: Downvoting for not actually posting the answer to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message and behavior are because of a problem with *pgpool authenticating to postgres*, not with you authenticating to pgpool as you might suspect.  If you check the postgres logs, it will tell you which line in your *postgres* `pg_hba.conf` is being rejected.

However, since (IIRC) pgpool cannot do peer authentication, it is probably this one, which says that all local (unix socket) connections will be authenticated by pretending the system username is the postgres username:

```
local all all peer
```

You want to change that to:

```
local all all trust
```

At least to make things work.  However, you will lose some security this way.  However, if all your users (that can access the unix socket) are trusted, this is okayish.

Comment: Thx for answer. Yes, I resolved it on postgres level, when had this problem. :)